# How to get the currently selected tab in office word VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to focus on tabs in my add in. Focusing on tabs is a bit expensive, so I would like to see if a focus is needed - if the selected tab is the one I need to set focus on, I want to skip the focusing phase.

I have searched a lot about this topic, and I couldn't find any any up-to-date information. I can't even find a corresponding API.

How can I get the currently selected tab? Is it impossible?
Maybe the only way is to do this manually, by using an external API to listen to mouse clicks?

I'm using Office word 2016, Visual studio community 2019.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.

You can use the [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) to know what tab is active.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find how to do it using this API. There is not enough information about this API, and no samples for C#, especially not any ribbon ones. If you could provide more details, or even share some code, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: As I wrote above, the Office extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. There is no trivial way to get this job done.

Comment: Not even the Accessibility API? I thought you said it's possible with this API